# Contract scoped memory variables in solidity

Tags: solidity, evm, reentrant-attacks

By my research I haven't found a way to have contract scoped memory variables. My objective is to have a `mutex` like the one described here https://www.blunderingcode.com/writing-secure-solidity/ but avoid the gas spending for changing state variables (I understand it is 5000 gas according to that article after the zeroing refund)